# How can I use PostCSS with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, postcss

Rails uses SCSS by default, and it's not too difficult to switch to Sass.

Is there any way to use PostCSS as the preprocessor? I'd naturally have to be able to specify extensions (and the order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails provides [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) now. If you use webpack to manage your assets, you can enable PostCSS. I believe PostCSS is enabled by default in webpacker now.

PostCSS [tweeted in 2015](https://twitter.com/postcss/status/681795745012396033?lang=en):

> Unfortunately, you should move to Gulp or webpack if you want to use PostCSS in Rails

Answer (score -1):

You can try using  `gem "autoprefixer-rails"`

Comment: I'm not just looking for autoprefixer. I'm looking for custom plugins, like cssnext and many others.